# PostgreSQL 10 error relation new doesn't exist on before update trigger

Tags: postgresql

My before update trigger throws an error on updating single row in table company.

```
ERROR:  relation "new" does not exist, row 7.
```

Trigger and trigger function code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.check_company_transitivity()
    RETURNS trigger
    AS $$
DECLARE
    cmp uuid;
    head_company uuid;
    audited_company uuid;
BEGIN
    audited_company := (select NEW.id from NEW);
    cmp:=audited_company;
    head_company:='*';
    while head_company is not null loop
        head_company:=(select head_company from company where id=cmp);
        if audited_company=head_company then
            raise exception 'transitive closure';
        else
            cmp=head_company;
        end if;
    end loop;
return new;
END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;


create trigger check_company_transitivity 
before update
on
public.company for each row execute procedure check_company_transitivity();
```

I can’t understand what the problem is, I would be appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the values from `NEW` directly

```
audited_company := NEW.id;
```